# How to get Chrome Performance tool summary through selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, google-chrome-devtools, performance-testing

I want to run chrome performance tool for my site and want to get summary of the result through selenium webdriver(Java).
I have searched alot but didn't found any solution.
Below is the screenshot of the summary generated after running of performance tool.
[screenshot of data I wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJEaW.jpg)

Comment: You can get that summary in `json` format and you can load it whenever you want to view or you can find some mechanism to convert that `json` to `html`

Comment: Best way is to use  a RUM add in for your browser which then dumps the standard web performance metrics to a common location for analysis.   See Boomerang javascript add in and Boomcatch as examples

Comment: @AliCSE  Thanks for the reply. Can you please tell me how and from where l can get summary in json format through selenium webdriver.

Comment: @Monika sethi, here is the thing - after navigating to the Performance summary screen, if you do the right click then you can see two options (1). Load profile and (2). Save profile - So you can save it to the file using Save Profile option and later you can Load it back whenever you need it. File type is json here - I hope it helps

Comment: @AliCSE Json file generated by chrome dev tool doesn't have summary data. Still not able to fetch data through selenium

Comment: @Monikasethi, Check out this links, you may find something helpful [Link1](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/timeline-tool#make-a-recording), [Link2](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference), [Link3](https://gist.github.com/axemclion/079f8bf1a997e9cfe9f0)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little late for the OP, but this is the first question I hit while looking for this myself, so I'm leaving the answer here.

They explain how to get the DevTools object here, which you can use to take a performance profile.  All the Performance data is available in the returned metrics object:
https://applitools.com/blog/selenium-4-chrome-devtools/#h.sbvz37d64nn4

If this link above breaks you can find it on the WayBack Machine here:
https://web.archive.org/web/20220809065253/https://applitools.com/blog/selenium-4-chrome-devtools/#h.sbvz37d64nn4